# How to hide jQuery tabs until authenticated and add or show them once authenticated in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, partial-views, jquery-ui-tabs

> **Summary**

I'm currently trying to build a Web application using MVC 3 architecture and jQuery UI controls. I have been able to display tabs and navigate through them so far.

Now, I am able to get the LogOn page to display on my first tab as it is the first required action to this application.

Once authenticated, I'd like to be able to add some other tabs which allows to use use this application.

The application is about a phone book listing containing known people mailing address.

That said, the workflow of this application would be:

1. Authenticate upon first arrival on the site;
2. If the user is not yet registered, the app shall let this very user register once and for all, using the same jQuery UI tab or maybe showing a new tab for registration or else, a modal dialog box;
3. Once authenticated from step 1, the user has now access to the different features of the site.

For example, let's say I want to register a new user and I am this web-application administrator. I shall first authenticate against this application, and then I'll see the common tabs that any user can see, plus a special tab for creating/registering new users who'll be able to authenticate against this app. once registered successfully by the site admin.

I have already been able to display the LogOn view which I deleted the initial view created by the template to recreate as a partial view to be able to contain it within the jQuery UI tab body. This works fine.

I also have a SelectTab method within my HomeController which shall know what partial view to display depending on the value of the id it is passed in as an input parameter.

Now, when I try to navigate from the LogOn partial view on the first jQuery UI tab, that is actually the only available option yet, clicking the Register link won't let me show the Register partial view within the same tab.

> **Code samples**

The HomeController class:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }

    public ActionResult SelectTab(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0: return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
            default: return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
        }
    }
}
```

The AccountController class:

```
public class AccountController {
    public ActionResult LogOn() { return PartialView(new LogOnModel()); }
    public ActionResult Register() { return PartialView(new RegisterModel()); }
}
```

Both models (LogOnModel, RegisterModel) stated here are the template's default.

And my _Layout.cshtml shared view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({ select: function (event, ui) { selectTab(getSelectedTab()); } });
            logIn();
        });

        function logIn() {
            selectTab(-1);
            selectTab(0);
        }

        function selectTab(index) {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/Home/SelectTab/")' + index;
            var targetDiv = "#tab" + index;
            $.get(url, null, function(result) { $(targetDiv).html(result); });
        }

        function getSelectedTab() { return $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected"); }
        function setSelectedTab(index) { $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", index); }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#tab0"><span>Authenticate</span></a></li>
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
                <li><a href="#tab1"><span>About</span></a></li>
            }
        </ul>
        <div id="tab0"></div><div id="tab1"></div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

> **Development environment**

I'm using:

1. VS2010 and .NET 4.0;
2. jQuery UI (see _Layout.csthml code sample for version and style template);
3. ASP.NET MVC3.

> **Question(s)**

*How to render the Register partial view once one clicks the 'Register' link contained in the 'LogOn' partial view into the same tab?

Perhaps hiding the actual tab and showing another for registration would appear to be simpler? And yet, how to achieve this?*

Comment: Do you refresh the page after logon?

Comment: I thought I could perhaps avoid it, if this is doable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that every other tab (except login) to be loaded via ajax. You submit the login from via ajax and on succesful response you destroy the login tab then add dynamically a new one with href set to an ajax action.

You can accomplish what you want to do, but it will require lots of jquery and ajax (I recommend to give [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) a try).The server-side part is the easiest one.

I think it's also better to call the actions directly without the SelectTab switch.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the hints. Aside, I'm from an industrial and framework background so I'm not familiar to work with AJAX and all the different Web technologies. I read about Knockout following your link, and I am going to give it a try for sure. Beside, I thought jQuery and jQuery UI was the leading technology along with ASP.NET MVC, so I thought I would try this hard work so that I can learn "the hard way", so once done, I would completely understand everything I had to use in order to achieve what I want to. I begin to believe that I bit more than I can chew, humbly.

Comment: What your code would look like if you'd want to do what I wish? Some start guidance shall be pretty much appreciated as I want to get better in developing Web apps, since the "world" is turning toward it. Providing an example to obtain the desired objective will grant you an accepted answer for sure. I swear to you. Thanks for your kindness and help!